# Type of `ListT`-done-right monad transformer

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I consider the `ListT` monad transformer surprisingly tricky. The following implementation that assumes a commutative base monad is hard enough:

```
instance (Monad m) => Monad (ListT m) where
    return a = ListT $ return [a]
    m >>= k  = ListT $ do
        a <- runListT m
        b <- mapM (runListT . k) a
        return (concat b)
```

It needs applicative to apply the effect of the base monad to the list values. However, the transformer from the list-t package baffles me:

```
instance Monad m => Monad (ListT m) where
  return a =
    ListT $ return (Just (a, (ListT (return Nothing))))
  (>>=) s1 k2 =
    ListT $
      uncons s1 >>=
        \case
          Nothing ->
            return Nothing
          Just (h1, t1) ->
            uncons $ k2 h1 <> (t1 >>= k2)
```

I am rather bad at reading Haskell code but if we assume `Maybe` as base monad it seems to me that the `bind` operation expects a value like `(Just 1:2:3:[]):[]` for its first argument. Shouldn't it be `Just 1:2:3:[]`?

This is probably connected to the lazy requirement of `ListT` in order to respect associativity, but I am not able to put everything together.

Comment: Uncons produces `m (Maybe (a, ListT m a))` where `m` can be `Maybe` in your case, resulting in a nested `Maybe (Maybe ...)` value. I think assuming `m=Maybe` does not help visualizing what's going on, but rather makes it harder, since it's then easy to mix the two layers. Consider another monad `m` to help intuition.

Comment: @chi I think I got the gist of what confused me. I assumed `uncons :: ListT m a -> m (Maybe (a, ListT m a))` would play the same role as `uncons :: [a] -> Maybe (a, [a])`. But it seems the former just peels off the transformer wrapper `ListT`, right?

Comment: @chi Sorry, I should have looked more closely into the types.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, it only peels off the wrapper. But, in a sense, it does play the role of the "other" `uncons`, except that is works in the monad on top of the `Maybe` result.

Comment: @chi The implementation is `uncons (ListT m) = m` where `m` is in WHNF I guess, i.e. this works due to lazyness. It is such a beautiful implementation, breathtaking!